# I got this error on laravel blade file -ErrorException A non well formed numeric value encountered on helper funtion

Tags: laravel, laravel-helper

Form helper get string value. Then convert numeric value. Other helper functions work properly but only this portion doesn't work.

```
    if(isset($result[$product->id])){
       $productArray[$product->id]+= @helper::getCtnQty($product->id,$result[$product->id]); // Error get from this line. but when dd I get value in int form
       $singleProductArray[$product->id]  = $productArray[$product->id];              
       <td style="text-align:center;font-weight: 700">
         {{@helper::getCtnQty($product->id,$result[$product->id])}}
       </td>
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed integer value for code but I get string. And This error usually pops up when we try to add an integer with a string or some type of non numeric field.

So, firstly I check type by gettype(). Then write (int) before helper function.

```
    if(isset($result[$product->id])){
        $productArray[$product->id]+= (int)@helper::getCtnQty($product->id,$result[$product->id]); 
        $singleProductArray[$product->id]  = $productArray[$product->id];              
     <td style="text-align:center;font-weight: 700">
       {{@helper::getCtnQty($product->id,$result[$product->id])}}
     </td>
    }
```